# THREE.js - Overlap two scenes without clearing the first one

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to render two scenes on top of each other however the second scene in the render cycle is completely removing the first scenes content.

My renderer is setup like this:

```
this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true,
  alpha: false,
  preserveDrawingBuffer: true
});
this.renderer.autoClear = false;
```

I'm using `preserveDrawingBuffer` because I need to export a portion of the renderer as a PNG and needed it to, well, preserve its buffer.

After creating my first scene, I create its composer that looks something like this:

```
let renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass(this.scene, this.camera);
var effectCopy = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.CopyShader);
effectCopy.renderToScreen = true;

var rtParameters = {
        minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
        magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
        format: THREE.RGBAFormat,
        stencilBuffer: true
    };

this.composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(this.renderer,
    new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(this.width, this.height, rtParameters));
this.composer.setSize(this.width, this.height);
this.composer.addPass(renderPass);
this.composer.addPass(effectCopy);
```

Then I create my second Scene, and its composer looks the exact same, except it also has a `THREE.FXAAShader` added to its composer.

Finally my update function looks like this:

```
update() {
    this.renderer.clear();

    // They're actually different sizes and positions, so i move the viewport. But this snippet ive left them the same
    this.renderer.setViewport(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    this.composer1.render();

    this.renderer.setViewport(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    this.composer.render();
...
}
```

I've tried changing the Scenes backgrounds, and playing with the renderers `alpha`, `autoclear`, and `preserveDrawingBuffer` but cant get it working

**EXAMPLE**

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pn4L4L07/2/) example of two scenes where the one is clipping the other one.

Comment: (1) I do not think you need to set `preserveDrawingBuffer` as long as you re-render immediately prior to calling `toDataURL()`. (2) Does this three.js example work for you?: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_advanced.html

Comment: Try `this.composer1.clearDepth()` between the two render calls

Comment: @WestLangley Thanks for the tip! Ive taken a look at that example for my post processing and running multiple scenes but it didnt help with putting them on top of each other.

Comment: @AndyRay composer.clearDepth() doesnt exist, But adding `this.renderer.clearDepth()` didnt help either. (Tried it everywhere!). I'll setup a jsfiddle now

Comment: I've added a JSFiddle example of it not working. Maybe either of you guys could help me figure this one out

Comment: Yeah, when rendering to the screen, compositing is done with the webpage. You will have to figure out some other approach, and that may take some work... Something like passing in the render target of the first composer into the constructor of the second, and rendering to the screen only once. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Since three.js r83, `RenderPass` now has a `clearDepth` property. You can set this to `true` on your second scene `RenderPass` and that should allow for the second scene to render on top of the first.